# Show/hide a fieldset using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following html code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>
                <button>
                    Show/Hide form
                </button>
            </legend>
            Name:
            <input type="text" />
            <br />
            Email:
            <input type="text" />
            <br />
            Date of birth:
            <input type="text" />
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>
                <button>
                    Show/Hide form
                </button>
            </legend>
            Name:
            <input type="text" />
            <br />
            Email:
            <input type="text" />
            <br />
            Date of birth:
            <input type="text" />
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>
                <button>
                    Show/Hide form
                </button>
            </legend>
            Name:
            <input type="text" />
                <br />
            Email:
            <input type="text" />
                <br />
            Date of birth:
            <input type="text" />
        </fieldset>

    </body>
</html>
```

But how i can show and hide a field set if the user clicks on the "show/hide form"  button AND is there a way to change the button label to be either show or hide based on the current status of the field set?
BR

Comment: if you hide the fieldset the button will be hidden too

Comment: Not if you perform a hide like so: `$("button").parent().siblings().hide();`

Comment: @Flater Very inefficient, and using a legend for the toggle button isn't the correct use anyway.

Comment: But it is code-wise the easiest way to hide everything in a fieldset except the <legend>. Unless you want to add classes to every other child element (which isn't always an option). Also, people often make remakrs that fieldsets aren't being used how they should. To be honest I don't agree. If it's functional and looks great, use it. Fieldsets look a lot better than bordered divs with a <h3> inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `fieldset` is hidden your button is hidden too. You can modify your markup and use `toggle` method:

```
<button class='toggle'>Hide</button>
<fieldset>
Name: <input type="text" /><br />
Email: <input type="text" /><br />
Date of birth: <input type="text" />
</fieldset>
```

```
$('.toggle').click(function(){
   var $this = $(this);
   $this.text( $this.text() == 'Show' ? "Hide" : "Show" )
   $this.next().toggle()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML CODE:

```
<button>Show/Hide form</button>

    <fieldset>
    <legend></legend>
    Name: <input type="text" /><br />
    Email: <input type="text" /><br />
    Date of birth: <input type="text" />
    </fieldset>
    <br />
    <button>Show/Hide form</button>
    <fieldset>
    <legend></legend>
    Name: <input type="text" /><br />
    Email: <input type="text" /><br />
    Date of birth: <input type="text" />
    </fieldset>
    <br/>
    <button>Show/Hide form</button>
    <fieldset>
    <legend></legend>
    Name: <input type="text" /><br />
    Email: <input type="text" /><br />
    Date of birth: <input type="text" />
    </fieldset>
```

YOur jQuery CODE:

```
 $(function(){
        $('button').click(function(){  
                if( $(this).html()=='Show/Hide form') $(this).html('Hide');
            $(this).nextAll('fieldset:first').toggle();

            $(this).html()=='Show'?($(this).html('Hide')):($(this).html('Show'));
        });
    })
```

Your JSFIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/bzAkL/