# How can I hide a fieldset (and disable the associated ASP.NET validation for that fieldset) based on a radio button selection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have three different radio button items with a name of "RegistrantType".

Based on what the user selects, a different fieldset is shown.   How do I most efficiently show / hide the fieldsets.   I also need to disable any ASP.NET validation that may exist in the hidden fieldsets:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend id="legend">Registration</legend>
    <ol>
        <li>
            <label for="RegistrantType">Please select your registrant type:</label>
            <br />
            <div id="RegistrantType">
                <!-- Subscriber -->
                <input runat="server" type="radio" name="RegistrantType" id="RegistrantTypeSubscriber" value="1" />
                <label runat="server" for="SuspsectTypeSubscriber">Subscriber</label>
                <fieldset runat="server" id="RegistrantTypeSubscriberFields">
                    <legend>
                        Subscriber
                    </legend>
                    <ol>
                        <li>
                            <input runat="server" type="text" name="RegistrantSubscriberID" placeholder="Subscriber ID" />
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </fieldset>

                <!-- Promo -->
                <input runat="server" type="radio" name="RegistrantType" id="RegistrantTypePromo" value="2"  />
                <label for="SuspsectTypePromo">Promo Code</label>
                <fieldset runat="server" id="RegistrantTypePromoFields">
                    <legend>
                        Promo
                    </legend>
                    <ol>
                        <li>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </fieldset>

                <!-- New Sign Up -->
                <input runat="server" type="radio" name="RegistrantType" id="RegistrantTypeNew Sign Up" value="3" />
                <label for="SuspsectTypeNew Sign Up">New Sign Up</label>
                <fieldset runat="server" id="RegistrantTypeNew Sign UpFields">
                    <legend>
                        New Sign Up
                    </legend>
                    <ol>
                        <li>
                            <input runat="server" type="text" name="RegistrantFirstName" id="RegistrantFirstName" placeholder="*First Name" maxlength="128" />
                            <input runat="server" type="text" name="RegistrantLastName" id="RegistrantLastName" placeholder="*Last Name" maxlength="128" />
                            <br />
                            <input runat="server" type="text" name="RegistrantPhoneNumber" id="RegistrantPhoneNumber" placeholder="*Phone Number" maxlength="14"/>
                            <br />
                            <input runat="server" type="text" name="RegistrantStreetAddress01" id="RegistrantStreetAddress01" placeholder="*Address" maxlength="128" />
                            <input runat="server" type="text" name="RegistrantStreetAddress02" id="RegistrantStreetAddress02" placeholder="Address"  maxlength="128"/>
                            <br />
                            <input runat="server" type="text" name="RegistrantCity" id="RegistrantCity" placeholder="*City" maxlength="128" />
                            <asp:dropdownlist runat="server" id="RegistrantState"></asp:dropdownlist>
                            <input runat="server" type="text" name="RegistrantZIP" id="RegistrantZIP" placeholder="*ZIP Code" maxlength="10" />
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </li>
                     <!-- Rest of form removed for brevity... -->
    </ol>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13759886/how-to-show-and-hide-fieldset-content-on-click-of-the-legend   and    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194054/show-hide-a-fieldset-using-jquery

Comment: The second URL appears to have some info that could send me down the right path of toggling the visibility.   Neither seem to mention anything about deactivating specific validations though.

Answer (score 2):

You can manipulate fields sets like this:

```
<fieldset id="fs1" runat="server">
    I'm one
</fieldset>

<fieldset id="fs2" runat="server">
    I'm two
</fieldset>

// in the code behind
fs1.Visible = true;
fs2.Visible = false;
```